# Как сделать запрос?

Tags: sql, h2

В SQL умею делать простые запросы. Есть три таблицы. Необходимо для каждого пользователя получить помесячно среднюю стоимость его покупок.

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
  userId BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  age INT
);


CREATE TABLE Items(
itemId BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
price DOUBLE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Purchases(
purchaseId BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
userId INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT users_userid_fk FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES Users(userId),
itemId INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT items_itemid_fk FOREIGN KEY (itemId) REFERENCES Items(itemId),
date DATE NOT NULL,
);
```

Comment: СУБД у Вас какая?

Comment: *В SQL умею делать простые запросы.* Требуемый запрос относится к простым. Где ВАШИ попытки решить задачу? И по возможности с пояснениями, почему именно так.

Comment: H2 использую. Над попытками думаю. Что именно так?

Comment: Почему именно так написан запрос в Вашей попытке. По каждой секции, полю, условию...

Comment: такое условие задачи

Comment: я попробовал вот так SELECT avg(price) FROM Items GROUP BY (Purchases.date, Users.userId); - но пока что ошибка вылетает

Comment: с поправкой на диалект БД и фильтр по дате, попробуйте `SELECT p.userId, AVG(i.price) FROM Items i JOIN Purchases p ON i.itemId = p.itemId WHERE p.date > '2018-03-01' GROUP BY p.userId;`

Comment: какую роль выполняет WHERE p.date > '2018-03-01' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Групируешь все покупки по идентификатору пользователя и по месяцам (парсиш дату), получаешь общую сумму и к-во, ну и добавляешь вычисление средней стоимости.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, решил вот так:

```
SELECT p.userId, AVG(i.price) FROM Items i JOIN Purchases p ON i.itemId = p.itemId WHERE MONTH(p.date) GROUP BY p.userId;
```

Comment: Решение ошибочно. 1) Не соответствует заданию. 2) Вообще лишено логики.

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Comment: В вопросе идёт речь про `получить помесячно среднюю стоимость его покупок`; этот запрос не группирует по месяцам. Проверьте результат, когда есть по несколько покупок за разные месяцы. С группировкой по месяцам должно быть что-то в духе `SELECT p.userId, MONTH(p.date) as month, AVG(i.price) FROM Items i JOIN Purchases p ON i.itemId = p.itemId GROUP BY p.userId, month;`

Comment: Да, я вот на таком варианте остановился. SELECT p.userId , AVG(i.price), MONTH(p.date) FROM Items i JOIN Purchases p ON i.itemId = p.itemId WHERE MONTH(p.date) GROUP BY MONTH(p.date), p.userId ORDER BY userId, month(p.date);